# How do you Get the Unity Launcher to Autohide underneath other windows while not autohiding when all Windows are un-maximised?

Tags: 12.10, launcher

That is suppose you have google chrome open or some other program how can we get the unity launcher to autohide when it (the program) is open and maximised but to reappear when it's unmaximised (i.e. it doesn't cover the entire desktop). I am running 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can either let the launcher hide always, or never. "Intellihide" and "dodge windows" are removed from unity since ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't, or at least not by default. <del>However, if you install Unity Tweak Tool, I think it may let you do this.</del>

Comment: They removed that capability from Unity itself, so Ubuntu-Tweak can't do it.

Comment: @jesusiniesta Had a feeling that was the case, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

They removed that capability from Unity, as far as I know, so as handuel said: you can't... but.

There is thogh a custom build of unity that re-enable a similar behaviour, in which the dock will hide only when it would collide with a window. This is not official code from Canonical, but it comes from an, IMHO, very reliable source, webupd8.

You can install such a patched version of Unity (from webupd8 great repositories):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
```

And then, to get the "real" Unity Dodge Windows

```
sudo apt-get install unity-dodge-windows
```

Once installed, press ALT + F2 and run:

```
unity-dodge-windows
```

Source, from webupd8: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-get-unity-launcher-window-dodge.html

Comment: I'm afraid this does not solve my problem. The unity launcher disappear indiscriminately, i.e. it does not reappear when all windows are out of its way or even when they're all minimised. I went to alter the behaviour of the unity launcher with System Settings -- Appearance and this failed because when I switched the launcher not to autohide it immediately reverted back to autohide. Plus the launcher still reappears when I go to the left-hand corner of my page even when other programs are overlapping it.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Did you try setting "Have file manager handle the desktop" to OFF?

Comment: I'm afraid it still has this problem even after this adjustment